# Is there a way to have a redirecting html page as the source for an image?

Tags: javascript, css, image, random

Basically, I want to set a html page as the source for an image - then this page redirects to a random image from a folder.

I tried to just use the html page as the source - and the JavaScript in the html page works fine - and redirects to a random image

But how do I make it take this image, rather than the html page itself?

Comment: I don't think you actually need an HTML page. Probably just an endpoint (URL) that responds with a random image. The response might set HTTP redirect header so the client would go to another URL to download the image. The point is the response can't have text/html content-type or the client (browser) can't help but interpret it as HTML.

Comment: You cannot do this in client side with html and javascript. It has to be done in the server via PHP, java and any other server side language.

Comment: I don't think the img src element can be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I make it take this image, rather than the html page itself?

That's the point. Browsers look at content-type header in order to understand how to show the content. If they see "text/html" they can't help but show the page itself, it doesn't matter that it has client-side JavaScript making redirects - the initial request already got HTML as the response. If you're making these requests using `img` element it'd be just an error since the browser doesn't know how to "draw HTML", only images (the right content-type should be set as well).

I believe what you need is to set up proper server-side logic for your endpoint. It could set the Location header that points to a random image URL.